# YarnClient runtime exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/HadoopIllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am working with YarnClient for the 1st time. My goal is to get and display the applications running on Yarn using Java. My project setup is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, YarnException {
    // Create yarnClient
    YarnConfiguration conf = new YarnConfiguration();
    YarnClient yarnClient = YarnClient.createYarnClient();
    yarnClient.init(conf);

    try {
        List applications = yarnClient.getApplications();
        System.err.println("yarn client : " + applications.size());
    } catch (YarnException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I get the following exception when i run the program:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/HadoopIllegalArgumentException
at projects.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:16)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.HadoopIllegalArgumentException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

The POM file is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>BigContent</groupId>
    <artifactId>ManagementServer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <hadoop.version>2.4.0</hadoop.version>
        <spark.version>1.2.1</spark.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- First step is to disable the default-war build step. -->
                        <id>default-war</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Second step is to create an exploded war. Done in prepare-package -->
                        <id>war-exploded</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exploded</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Last step is to make sure that the war is built in the package phase -->
                        <id>custom-war</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                            <directory>resource2</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>json-mapreduce</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-mapreduce</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.20.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>16.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Can you please help me in fixing the issue, or if you can suggest a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I changed the pom file's dependencies as follows and the
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.HadoopIllegalArgumentException` is fixed:

```
 <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

now i get a Null Pointer Exception at 
`List applications = yarnClient.getApplications();` trying to resolve that now.

Answer (score 0):

After running into this same issue and looking around a bit, I found that after the creation of the YarnClient object, and after init'ing it, you also need to call start() on the object. This resolved the NullPointer on my end

```
YarnConfiguration yarnConfig = new YarnConfiguration();
YarnClient client = YarnClient.createYarnClient();
client.init(yarnConfig);
client.start();

client.getAllQueues(); //no longer throws NullPointer
```